# Will RESULT_CACHE keyword return updated data from function in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, function

I am calling function inside select query of view. View is reading records from table which contains around 1 million records. 
When I am writing RESULT_CACHE key word in function, I am getting output in fraction of seconds. I have doubt that when value of any column is changed which is used inside view, will function consider that new value?

Comment: can you share code snap?

Comment: Please provide the code sample. so we can help you.

Comment: In some circumstances the function result will be cached within the scope of execution in a single SQL statement anyway, based on whether it is deterministic and on changes to the input parameters, regardless of the RESULT_CACHE setting. Are you sure you need RESULT_CACHE?

Comment: Also, have you read the documentation for your version, to see what the documented behaviour is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my knowledge RESULT_CACHE will provide you the data from oracle special in-memory result cache.

if you want to get updated result you can use,
RESULT_CACHE RELIES_ON (TABLE NAME).

But if your DB version is 11.2 or higher then RELIES ON clause is unnecessary as it automatically tracks dependencies and invalidates the cached results when necessary.

you can refer from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2010/10-sep/o57plsql-088600.html) or [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/cross-session-plsql-function-result-cache-11gr1) in details

Comment: relies_on clause is deprecated  in oracle 11.2

Comment: Actually, `RELIES_ON` is *ignored* in Oracle 11.2+

Comment: @Jeffrey, can u please provide the link for better understanding.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/function.htm#LNPLS1597 "relies_on_clause does nothing"

Answer (score 1):

Yes I think it will refresh your data. 
But after updating data It will take time to execute first time.